# drop down list value in asp.net (by Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Drop Down List Problem

I have a fairly simple question.

I have a drop down list that is populated by a table in my sql database. Now I am retrieving values into a drop down list but these values go to the last row in the drop down list (value is machine1). Now I want to get value on top by user select Employee name.

[image]

Code:

```
string select = "select * from dally_report where Emp_name='" + txt_search.SelectedItem.ToString()+ "'";
   MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(select, DBConnection.connection());
   MySqlDataAdapter sp = new MySqlDataAdapter();
   MySqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read()) 
        {
            txt_date.Text = dr[2].ToString();
            txt_empname.Text = dr[1].ToString();
            txt_jobno.Text = dr[3].ToString();
            txt_machine1.Items.Add (dr[4].ToString()); // This is drop down list
        }
```

Comment: think you need to try and be more clear. it is hard to understand what is going on and what you are looking for. What is "lat row" and what is "value" that you want on top

Comment: I retrieve data from database in to drop down list but this value show in last value in my drop down list i want to get it top please watch in my picture link

Comment: if you have column of datetime  in your **sql table** like Ex: dbAddedOn or dbInsertedOn then you can use it,in **Where** clause in your query to display it in first position.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using Items.Add try to use Items.Insert with index no 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drp_district" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drp_district_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off"></asp:DropDownList>

   protected void drp_district_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string value = drp_district.SelectedValue;

            _objdll.TableName = "tbl_assemblydetails";
            _objdll.Condition = "district_id";
            _objdll.Value = value;

            DataSet ds_assembly = _objdal.Fn_GEN_SelectAll_1Condition(strcommoncon, _objdll);
            if (ds_assembly.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                drp_assembly.DataTextField = "assembly_english".ToUpper();
                drp_assembly.DataValueField = "assembly_id";
                drp_assembly.DataSource = ds_assembly;
                drp_assembly.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                drp_assembly.DataSource = null;
                drp_assembly.DataBind();
                drp_assembly.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Assembly", "0"));
            }
    }
```